# Built a multidimensional array with PHP from an SQL query

Tags: php, arrays

Form a SQL query i receive the following datas from two differences tables.

```
|----------------|----------|--------------|
|CON_ContinentId | FRU_Name | FRU_Quantity |
|----------------|----------|--------------|
| 1              | Apple    | 100          |
| 1              | Banana   | 200          |
| 2              | Peach    | 300          |
| 2              | Cherry   | 400          |
| 3              | Coconut  | 500          |
| 4              | Grape    | 1100         |
| 5              | Pear     | 1500         |
|----------------|----------|--------------|
```

I need to get an array like this:

```
$datas = [ 
    1 => [ 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Apple', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '100'
        ], 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Banana', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '200'
        ]
    ],
    2 => [ 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Peach', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '300'
        ], 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Cherry', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '400'
        ]
    ],
    3 => [ 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Coconut', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '500'
        ]
    ],
    4 => [ 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Grape', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '1000'
        ]
    ],
    5 => [ 
        [
            'FRU_Name' => 'Pear', 
            'FRU_Quantity' => '1100'
        ]
    ],
]
```

So, basically, I need to groupe the rows with the same `CON_ContinentId` and list the `FRU_Name` and `FRU_Quantity`.

What I try:

```
$datas = [];

while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $CON_ContinentId = $fetch['CON_ContinentId'];
    $FRU_Name = $fetch['FRU_Name'];
    $FRU_Quantity = $fetch['FRU_Quantity'];

    if (!in_array($CON_ContinentId, $datas)) {
        $datas = array(
            'CON_ContinentId' => $CON_ContinentId,
            'FRU_Name' => $FRU_Name,
            'FRU_Quantity' => $FRU_Quantity
        );
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks.

Comment: would you show us the result of $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) by

var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every iteration of your results set, just use the `CON_ContinentID` value as the key, then `[]` to auto-index the subarrays.

There is no need to declare resultset values to new variables, just apply them to the `$datas` declaration and move on.

```
while ($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $datas[$fetch['CON_ContinentId']][]=['FRU_Name'=>$fetch['FRU_Name'],'FRU_Quantity' =>$fetch['FRU_Quantity']];
}
```

a bit more explanation...

```
//                   hard-coded keys -vvvvvvvv-----------------------vvvvvvvvvvvv
$datas[$fetch['CON_ContinentId']][]=['FRU_Name'=>$fetch['FRU_Name'],'FRU_Quantity' =>$fetch['FRU_Quantity']];
//  id-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^-auto-index   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-resultset data
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^-keys start from zero, and increment by one at each new pushed subarray)
```

Comment: Ho it's working man. Thanks so much for your additional explanations. It helps me a lot.

Comment: Thanks mickmackusa!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different problems in your code:

1. Your desired array structure isn't valid, so it's unclear what you want.
2. `$datas` isn't initialized. Use `$datas = []` instead.
3. `$FRU_Name` is being set twice? Did you mean `$FRU_Quantity`?
4. This code won't group multiple fruits under their continent ID--it'll put them into an associative array alongside their continent ID.

Comment: Good Point! I didn't even notice that.  have to do `[ [ 'CON_ContinentId' => 1, ..], [ ...] ]`

Comment: Hello, I changed the code according to your helpful comments. Could you please try reach the goal? Thanks.

Comment: Your desired structure still isn't valid--you have arrays where there are two values with the same key.

Comment: Could you please propose me a new structure depending my need? I think you understand it. I'm looking my documentation near my wish but arrays are difficult for me.

Comment: something like `$continents = [ 1 => [ ['FRU_Name' => '...', 'FRU_Quantity'] => '...'],  ['FRU_Name' => '...', 'FRU_Quantity' => '...'] ], 2 => [ .. ] ]` is probably what you want.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm looking form. Question is now updated. Could you please help me to build it ?